# Forcing alphabetic-only input

Tags: c++, loops

I'm trying to program a text-based game for a project at school. I'm doing alright so far, but being the perfectionist I am I wanted to have alphabetic-only names for the player's character. I've been working on this for hours trying to find the solution. I think the problem might lie in the fact that I'm confusing myself with too many loops. Then again, I'm not really the best judge for that. Here's what I have in terms of code; it's a bit messy. Don't mind my goto usage..

```
while(cin >> name){
    for(int x = 0; x < name.length(); x++){
        char c = name.at(x);
        while(!isalpha(c)){
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
            cout << "Names are alphabetical only, with no spaces.\n";
            cin >> name;
            for(int x = 0; x < name.length(); x++){
                char c = name.at(x);
                if(isalpha(c))
                    goto breakingout;
            }
        }
    }
    breakingout:
        break;
}
```

A few other things I want that may have hindered me were that I wanted the error message to appear only once (it would appear multiple times on multiple non-alphabetic characters in one input) as well, so bonus points for anyone who can help me out with that :)

Comment: Taking the perfectionist claim seriously... are the names in Unicode with UTF-8 encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if a string contains any non-alpha characters you can use standard algorithms like [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), C++ also wraps `std::find_if` in helpful functions like [`std::all_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) which returns a `bool` instead of an `iterator`, i.e. :

```
bool containsOnlyAlphaChars = std::all_of(name.begin(), name.end(), [](char c){ 
   return std::isalpha(c);
});
```

Update: Your code can be re-written as:

```
bool containsOnlyAlphaChars = false;
while(!containsOnlyAlphaChars){
    std::cin >> name;

    containsOnlyAlphaChars = std::all_of(name.begin(), name.end(), [](char c){ 
        return std::isalpha(c);
    });

    if(!containsOnlyAlphaChars){
        std::cout << "Names are alphabetical only, with no spaces.\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe use [`std::all_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/all_of/) instead, it means you can avoid the `!` and makes it a bit more intuitive.

Comment: @BrannonPenrod It depends but probably :) Both `std::find_if` and `std::all_of` are defined in `<algorithm>`, so if your code is not compiling you could try including that header.

Comment: Where could I put this? In the loop? Sorry if it should be obvious, I'm still quite new to this.

Comment: @BrannonPenrod I've updated my answer to show how your current code could be re-written/simplified, hope it helps :) Oh, and you should avoid the use of `goto` as it leads to overly complex and unmaintainable code, there's rarely a reasonable use for it.

Comment: Thank you, so much! You're a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something more like this?

```
bool isDone = false;
while(!isDone)
{
    string input;
    getline(cin, input);
    isDone = true;
    for(int i = 0; i<input.size(); i++)
    {
        if(!isAlpha(input[i]))
            isDone = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works very well! Thank you. One thing though, if I type something like "b5b" as an input it will accept it anyway. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: @BrannonPenrod really? I just tried it and it did not like it

Comment: Maybe it's my ide? I'm using codeblocks. If that's bad let me know now haha

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one loop and a goto statement like this:

```
string name;
cout << "Enter your name: ";
cin >> name;

   breakingout:
   for(unsigned i = 0; i != name.size(); i++) {
       char c = name.at(i);
       if(!isalpha(c)) {
           cout << "Enter your name without numbers: ";
           cin >> name;
           goto breakingout;
       }
   }
```

Or with iterators like this, it's recommended in C++.

```
string name;
cout << "Enter your name: ";
cin >> name;

   breakingout:
   for(auto iter = name.cbegin(); iter != name.end(); iter++) {
       if(!isalpha(*iter)) {
           cout << "Enter your name without numbers: ";
           cin >> name;
           goto breakingout;
       }
   }
```